# how to import the config ts file in ionic2 other ts file

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

while import app.config.ts file in other ts file like /pages/home/home.ts

i have used following code in app.config

```
import { OpaqueToken } from "@angular/core";

    export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken("app.config");

    export interface IAppConfig {
        apiEndpoint: string;
    }

    export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {    
        apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:15422/api/"    
    };
```

please help me,to use this app.config and also defined in app.module

Comment: Did you set it as provider in app.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts`, set it as provider as:

```
{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConfig },
```

While Injecting in a class,

```
constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig,..){}
```

You can access your values as `config.apiEndpoint`